# Run function with different parameters depending on different element click?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm going through The Odin Project and I am at the 2nd stage of the Rock, Paper, Scissors project. I have already got all of the logic working using prompt to get the player selection and using the console for feedback, etc.

The 2nd part of the project asks me to make a GUI web site to play the game. I have three images that I've added a href="#" to and each image has its own unique id value. I can't seem to figure out how to get the particular value from which image the user clicks and use that id value as the parameter to the play game function when that particular image is clicked. I know I need to add an event listener to catch the click and somehow return the id value to be used in the function. The function simply takes the player selection (clicked image id) and compares it with the randomly generated computer selection and will change the text content of a separate div depending on the result.

Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT: Forgot to add GitHub repo for code! Also, figured out something that worked before looking at these answers, but I already appreciate the great feedback on the options I have available to accomplish this task. Please feel free to critique my code if it can be improved in any way! I still have some functionality to work on and connect to the html.

GitHub repo: https://github.com/dblinkhorn/rockPaperScissors

Comment: put three image or element, select through `querySelectorAll` or `getElementsByTagName` we do not use element `id` normally, so why `id` - put the minimal version of your project here or jsfiddle

Comment: Added the github repo for code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Any `function` you register as an event listener automatically gets passed the `event` object, when the event you registered the function for occurs.

This `event` object holds alot of information, amongst which you find which element the event actually occured on: `event.target`.

If you want to know the `id` of the element, just ask it:

```
function clickHandler(event) {
  console.log(event.target.id);
}
```

Example (I'm using `div`s here for simplifying the demo):

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div[id]');

for (const div of divs) div.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);

function clickHandler(event) {
  console.log(event.target.id);
}
```

```css
div[id] { background-color: #a00; color: #fff; padding: 50px; display: inline-block; }
div[id]::before { content: attr(id); }
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
<div id="bar"></div>
<div id="baz"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to see some of your code to give you better feedback, but a possible way to accomplish what you want is to use [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)

> The currentTarget read-only property of the Event interface identifies the current target for the event, as the event traverses the DOM. It always refers to the element to which the event handler has been attached [...]

```js
function onImgClick(event) {
  console.log(`you clicked the img with id "${event.currentTarget.id}"`)
}

const images = document.querySelectorAll("img")
for (const image of images) {
  image.addEventListener("click", onImgClick);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" id="img-1" />
  <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" id="img-2" />
  <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" id="img-3" />
</div>
```